# Looking for a "point ring"

Tags: navigation, mark-ring

Is there something like a point ring in Emacs?

I would like to store the current point in there using a command similar to `point-to-register`. But when I store another point, I want the previous one preserved. Later I want to list all the points in the ring and jump to one of them.

It would be really cool to have multiple of these rings and when these could be named and persisted.

Comment: You mean `point`, not `pointer`, correct? Maybe check out `push-mark` and friends.  Also do `C-h i g(emacs)Mark ring` to read the Emacs doc.

Comment: Point changes every time you move the cursor, so it it wouldn't be that useful (i.e., it would include every position you'd been at in a file). The mark-ring that Nick pointed you to is almost certainly more useful.

Comment: You got me wrong. I want to manually add points to the ring and manually recall them. Think of manually leaving breadcrumbs while browsing code.

Comment: Isn't that what `push-mark` is doing?

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the Emacs manual about the [`mark-ring`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mark-Ring.html) and the [`global-mark-ring`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Global-Mark-Ring.html).

The basics: Use `C-SPC` C-SPC`to set the mark at some location. (The first`C-SPC` is enough to set it, but if that's all you want to do then you use the second one to also deactivate the region (mark).)

Each time you do this the location is added to the `mark-ring`.  You can later use `C-u C-SPC` to return to the last-added location.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store positions only manually I have a library that can do that. It doesn't use a ring though, it uses a stack. You can download it from [Codeberg](https://codeberg.org/grese/.emacs.d/src/branch/master/local/non-elpa-packages/marker-stack/marker-stack.el). Put it in a path in your `load-path` (Type `C-h v load-path RET` to see its value) and in your `init.el` tell Emacs to load it

```lisp
(require 'marker-stack)
```

Then tell the library not to save positions automatically

```lisp
(setq marker-stack-functions-every-call nil)
(setq marker-stack-functions-first-call nil)
```

and bind the commands for saving a position and for navigating the history to some keys, for example

```lisp
(global-set-key [f5] 'marker-stack-push)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-,") 'marker-stack-backward-stack-pop)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-.") 'marker-stack-forward-stack-pop)
```

That should do. One day I'll upload it to MELPA.

Comment: This seams what I am looking for. Almost. It is buffer local. I would like it global.

Comment: @Witek Then take a look at the package I forked it from, https://github.com/dgutov/point-stack